# Why does one preg_match work but not the other

Tags: php, preg-match

I haven't worked with preg_match() too terribly much but I can not figure out why searching for 1 div like this:

```
$div = '<div class="ipsPageHeader ipsClearfix">';
preg_match("/".$div."(.*?)<\/div>/", $html, $matches); $content=md5($matches[0]);
```

But when I try to search for a div different div like this:

```
$div = '<div class="cPost_contentWrap ipsPad">';
preg_match("/".$div."(.*?)<\/div>/", $html, $matches); $content=md5($matches[0]);
```

It gives me this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Freelancer\citrix\steam.php on line 33
```

If you're curious what page I'm pulling from it's [Here](http://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/1468-xbox-patch-notes-current-v7300-and-upcoming-v7310/)

Basicaly, I'm taking the top post of this page to save and compare later to see if there have been changes

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the contents of `$html`. That's going to be where your problem is; it's probably a whitespace issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that particular page, there is no `<div class="cPost_contentWrap ipsPad">`, only `<div class='cPost_contentWrap ipsPad'>`. Notice that the one on the page uses single-quotes, while your regular expression uses double-quotes, meaning that the characters don't match and the search returns no results.

Comment: Wow I had no idea that actually made a difference. Thank you very much.